# modify a view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am doing my homework in Oracle.

I have to create a complex view and after creating the view, I have to modify it.

The question says that the creation of the view must be able to handle the situation when there is no `department_name` in existence. I am not sure if I have to use this `NVL(d.department_name, 'No department established yet')`

The second question is I have to modify the view to change the column names to aliases such as department_name to "Departments" and include other countries in the view that is not included in the view. The below is the view that I have created and I need help please.

```
CREATE VIEW jack_vu AS
SELECT NVL(d.department_name, 'No department established yet') "department_name"
     , l.city
     , l.state_province
  FROM locations l 
  JOIN departments d
    ON (l.location_id = d.location_id)
 WHERE UPPER(l.country_id) LIKE 'CA'
    OR UPPER(l.country_id) LIKE 'IT';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are on the right track here.
The NVL function is used to handle null values, so that seems to be ok. You are already using an alias "department_name". You can also use aliases for normal columns i.e.: select column_name as "alias" from table;

You can also use "create or replace view ..." to change an already existing view.

Comment: I actually used CREATE OR REPLACE. But I am not sure this will be considered as a modification of a view?

Comment: No, but if you want to create an already existing view you will first have to drop it. Or use create or replace.

Answer (score 1):

The NVL() is the right thing to do, but you'll never get a null value for the deparment_name (unless one is stored in the departments table) because your query is using an "INNER JOIN"

What you want is to use an outer join between locations and departments which will include locations in the result which are not (yet) assigned to a department.

The LIKE operator is not needed btw. as you are doing an equality check. To make adding countries easier, using an `IN` operator is going to be less typing (although the `OR` will work just fine)

```
SELECT ...
FROM locations l 
  LEFT JOIN departments d ON (l.location_id = d.location_id) -- the LEFT is the difference
WHERE UPPER(l.country_id) IN  ('CA','IT'); -- add more countries here.
```

You might want to read up on outer joins if you don't understand what is happening here (e.g. here: http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/17403/1954?pf=true)

You already know how to give a column a new name you already used that by supplying the alias "department_name" to the result of the NVL function. So if that should be named "Departments" just change the name. I personally prefer to use `AS` to introduce the column alias. I think it makes the intention clearer.

```
SELECT NVL(d.department_name, 'No department established yet') as "Departments"
```

Comment: ok thanks. But what about the modification? after creating the view

Comment: @ahmadhussain: use `CREATE OR REPLACE` as you already do. That **is** considered changing the view.